# mmap invalid argument error

Tags: c, linux

This is the first time I use mmap system call. I am getting invalid argument error and I do not understand why , obviously I missing something 
Please help me, thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


int main() {

    long pageSize = getpagesize () ; 

    size_t length = 4096 ;


    int * map = (int * ) mmap ( 0 , length , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_ANONYMOUS , 0 , 0 ) ; 
        if ( map == MAP_FAILED ) {

            perror ( " error mapping " ) ;

        }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Specifying MAP_SHARED flag solved my problem. Again thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify at least one of `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED` in the flags. Also, as the other answer says, you should have -1 as the file descriptor for portability, but that's not where your problem is (since you tagged this question with linux and linux ignores the file descriptor for anon mappings).

Comment: I wonder why `man mmap` doesn't mention explicitly that `MAP_ [PRIVATE|SHARED]` are required, as opposed to the not-so-clear explanation about having "exactly one", which is easily glossed over when skimming.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `0` as the file descriptor. Anonymous mappings should always use `-1` as the file descriptor, since they are not backed by a file. Also, as the other answer says, `MAP_ANONYMOUS` should be complemented by either `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`.

The correct way to call it would be:

```
int *map = mmap(0, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Note that the cast is not necessary since `mmap` returns `void *`.

Comment: I tried to pass -1 and I got the same error . I read man page for mmap and it says fd parameter is ignored when using MAP_ANONYMOUS.

Comment: @Art: correct, but even the Linux mmap man page says that for portability, `-1` should be preferred: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: The problem was solved but I would like to ask another question to understand exactly how I use int * map variable . What does this variable contain exactly and how to use it ?

Comment: It points to a chunk of memory which is aligned on a page boundary (most probably 4096). You can use it in the same way you would use a chunk of memory returned by `malloc`. In fact, `malloc` implementations nowadays usually rely on anonymous `mmap`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again yet I want to ask another question if it is okay for you . Does it matter the type of map variable ? For example I use here int but for this memory chunk I want to allocate some place for a struct too and any other variables. Is it possible and how ?

Comment: `map` can be of any pointer type, including a pointer to a struct.

Comment: Is it possible to parse that memory chunk ?

Comment: I mean can I use map say 10 byte for a struct , 4 byte for an integer , 1 byte for a char ?

Answer (score 1):

You've specified the incorrect flags and file descriptor. You want is an anonymous (not backed by a file) mapping. If that's the case, the correct call would be:

```
int *map = mmap(0, length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

MAP_ANONYMOUS flag to tells Linux there is no file. And you should pass -1 for the file descriptor, not 0.